# Preprocessor Directive in xib?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder

Despite searching all over the place, I can't find the answer to my question. So let's see how good y'all are. :)

I'm working on an app that uses an NSPopover which is only available in 10.7 Lion but I want the app to compile for 10.5 and higher. I'm using a preprocessor directive to wrap the related popover code which seems to do the trick... However, the last piece I'm still getting errors on is the .zib in Interface Builder. How do I go about cleaning up the errors shown in the Issues Navigator stating "Class Unavailable: NSPopover on Mac OS X versions prior to 10.7"?

```
#ifdef __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
    #if __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 1070
        @property (assign) IBOutlet NSPopover *popover;
    }
    #endif
#endif
```

The above works in xxx.h and xxx.m's, but how do I get around the .xib errors?

Despite the error (Red), it builds successfully. However am I wrong to expect the 10.7 features (popover) to work in 10.7 because they don't... What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you building two separate versions of your app, with one targeting 10.7+ and one targeting <10.7?  Or are you building a single binary that should dynamically create an `NSPopover` at runtime only if it's running on 10.7+?

Comment: In short, I was hoping to create a single binary that would run on 10.5 - 10.7 and use NSPopover if running 10.7.

Comment: @glassfish then Citron's answer is not what you want. The preprocessor runs at compile time and cannot detect what version of the OS the application will run on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use preprocessors for this but check for availability at runtime using `NSClassFromString()`. The preprocessor runs at compile time, thus it won't detect what system the app is being run on.

Create three nibs, one for each of 10.5, 10.6 and 10.7 and load the one you need (or do it in code), but pick which one at run time, not compile time, e.g.

```
MyVC *vc = nil;
if (NSClassFromString(@"NSPopover"))
{
    vc = [NSViewController initWithNibName:@"MyVC-Lion" bundle:nil];
}
else if (/* check for 10.6+ only features */)
{
    vc = [NSViewController initWithNibName:@"MyVC-SL" bundle:nil];
}
else
{
    vc = [NSViewController initWithNibName:@"MyVC" bundle:nil];
}
// ...
```

Comment: +1, this is the way to go.  Some people don't understand that the preprocessor doesn't get run at runtime.

Comment: Yep, but then you have N xib to maintain ... if you decide to rework the common part, you'll have N time the work to do. And the end application will be significantly bigger.

So, maybe in YOUR case/experience it's better to do that, in my own, I definitely prefer managing only 1 xib, and use a little build script to target different platforms. The bigger the UI, the more painful the "N xib" approach will be.

Edit: moreover, you probably can replace the preprocessor by a dynamic check to only initialize the 10.7 parts when needed (still programmatically to avoid many xibs)

Comment: @Citron Then just use the most complex NIB supported by your Deployment Target and add the rest in code, but do not use runtime checks rather than the preprocessor. Do you really want to manage multiple applications for different versions of the same OS?

Answer (score 1):

Not a real answer to your question, apologies, but 2 possible workarounds: isn't it possible to create 2 versions of your xib, and depending on the target, compile on or the other? This would be a bit more work to maintain, but if your UI is pretty stable, this should be the easiest way.

Or you could add your "10.7 specific" UI component(s) programmatically instead of using the IB. If you just have one or a few popovers, it shouldn't be to difficult to do, and the proprocessor guards would work fine.

Comment: Though I haven't tried this yet, it seems like a pretty valid approach to me. Thank you! I'm just getting my feet with with Objective-C and this is my first project, so yes, I'm very much a noob and not quite sure what my options are yet. Any tips on HOW to dynamically load elements based on which version of OS they're running?

Comment: short answer : preprocessor :) Just setup your whole UI in IB, then for 10.7 specific stuff, add them programmatically, using preprocessor to dectect wether you're building for 10.7 or 10.6 and lower.
As for "how to programmatically add elements", well, I think most (if not all) the cocoa controls (such as NSButton, etc.) inherit from NSView. And NSView have a few methods doing exactly what you want : addSubview, removeFromSuperView, etc. :)

Comment: This will not check dynamically, it'll require you to build three versions of your app!

Comment: Ok, replace the preprocessor by a runtime check. The point is : the UI parts which are common to all the supported versions goes to a XIB, and for the 10.7 specific stuff, add the programmatically.
Whether you decide to do this using preprocessor or at runtime is just personnal taste (small / fast application + N build to do (build script ...) versus bigger / slower application but just one build) (this is true for ALL preprocessor versus runtime check dilemnas ^^)